# AJAX Response NOT Appending Class as Expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on social site where each user can post and each post can be commented on. When the page loads for the first time, each post has two comments displayed and the remaining are hidden. The hidden ones get revealed when the `Load more` button is clicked. Each comment has a class `.per_comment` but the one returned ones via AJAX are wrapped within one class `.per_comment` and each of them will now have another class `.per_comment`. If I apply a click event to each comment using class `.per_comment, the first two that are displayed by default works fine but the ones returned via AJAX work as one since they are all within one class.

**HTML:**

```
<div class = 'rows'>
    <div class='feed_blocks'>
        <div class='feeds'>
        <!-- user post goes here -->
            <div class = 'comment_data'>
                <div class = 'per_comment'> 
                    <a href = '#'><p class = 'usernames'>username</p></a>
                    <div class = 'commenter_details'>
                        <p> commenter_full_name </p>
                    </div>
                    <p>comments..</p>
                </div>
                <div class = 'morecomments'><p> Load more </p> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div
</div
```

**jQuery AJAX:**

```
$(".comment_data").on('click', '.morecomments', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $pc = $this.prev('.per_comment');
    //if the comments are already loaded then don't load it again just display it
    if ($pc.data('loaded')) {
        $this.replaceWith("<div class = 'morecomments'><p> Load more </p> </div>");  
        $pc.slideDown();
    } else {
        var post_id = $(this).val();
        var user_id = $(".user_id").text();
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "comments.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                post: post_id,
                user: user_id
            },
            dataType: "html"
        });
        request.done(function (msg) {
            $pc.html(msg).data('loaded', true);
            $this.replaceWith("<div class = 'morecomments'><p> Load more </p> </div>"); 
    });
    }
});
```

**PHP: comments.php**

```
<?php
require_once('../connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['post']) && isset($_POST['user'])) 
{
$post_id = $_POST['post']; 
$user_id = $_POST['user']; 
$com = "SELECT a, b, c FROM abc ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 2, 1000";
    $q = $conn->prepare($com) or die("ERROR: " . implode(":", $conn->errorInfo()));
    $q->bindParam(1, $post_id);
    $q->execute();
    if($commentz = $q->fetchAll()){
     foreach ($commentz as $comment){

        echo "<div class = 'per_comment'>";
            echo "<a href = '#'><p class = 'usernames'> commenter_name  </p></a>";
            echo "<div class = 'commenter_details'>";
                echo "<p> commenter_full_name </p>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<p>comments... </p>";
            echo "<div class = 'comment_reply'>";
                echo "<span class = 'likecount'>Like</span>";
            echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
     }
}
}
?>
```

Any help that will help me resolve this will be appreciated.

Comment: append you html $('.comment_data').append(msg); and prevent the use of replaceWith() function .it doesnot work properly in IE. use html  instead of that. use a uniquer ID instead of class.

Answer (score 0):

append all those echo a variable and return.

```
$html='';//before foreach

    $html = '<div class = 'per_comment'><a href = '#'><p class = 'usernames'>'. commenter_name.'</p></a><div class = 'commenter_details'><p>'. commenter_full_name.' </p></div><p>"comments... "</p><div class = 'comment_reply'><span class = 'likecount'>Like</span></div></div>';

echo $html//@ end
```

Comment: Can you please explain how that code is going to work? Why `$html = '';` and won't this `$html '<div class = ....` return an **ERROR**?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you errors on **PHP: comments.php** ?

```
echo "<a href = '#'><p class = 'usernames'>" commenter_name  "</p></a>";
echo "<p>"comments... "</p>";
```

for text:

```
echo "<a href = '#'><p class = 'usernames'>commenter_name</p></a>";
echo "<p>comments... </p>";
```

for variable (but there is no declaration for $commenter_name ) :

```
echo "<a href = '#'><p class = 'usernames'>".$commenter_name."</p></a>";
```